# Ошибка unfortunately при неправильной верстке Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Добрый день

Работаю в Eclipse с ADT-для разработки моб. приложения под Android. С бэкендом проблем не возникает, но при редактировании .xml Layout'тов или прямо в view редакторе-возникают следующие проблемы: в предосмотре layout все отображается корректно, дебаг не указывает ошибок, все компилится, но когда запускается либо на железке, либо на эмуляторе-бывают ошибки *unfortunately* и т.д.
Решается проблема бэкапом старого .xml layout или буквально подвигаешь позицию какого-нибудь элемента типа ImageButton например.

Почему так происходит и можно ли до запуска приложения отследить ошибки в верстке?

Также заметил такую непонятную вещь: в файле .xml манифеста некоторые Активити в начале имеют ".", т.е. в одном из проектов было ".MainActivity", пробовал убирать точку в начале - приложуха падала.

Comment: там и должна быть точка, она вам мешает чем то, к чему столько вопорсительных восклицаний? ошибка unfortunately ... - значит общюю "отписку" системы, что все плохо, приложение сломалось, она пишет это на **любую ошибку**. Что именно случилось нужно узнавать в Logcat - там будет полный стектрейс ошибки. Происходить это все может по тысячи причин и гадать их или перечислять все никто не будет. И да, Eclipse для android умер уже пару лет назад.

Comment: я конечно извиняюсь, но в LogCat по верстке(расположению элементов на экране) ничего не видел!Вопрос то в том,что в коде классов нет траблов,они возникают при перемещении позиции элементов на экране в .xml Layout...Т.е. сравнить даже грубо с Javascript-там верстка неправильная-все видно на экране,все косяки,а здесь падает в ошибку не давая права понять в чем дело)

Comment: Тем не менее, если произошло падение, в стектрейсе будет причина падения, а вы уж разбирайтесь там из-за чего это могло произойти и что не надо двигать. На ваш вопрос невозможно ответить предметно, только общие фразы. Не знаю как там в Eclipse, Android Studio дает множество варнингов в окне визуального редактирования при проблемах в верстке.

Comment: Привык в Eclipse, много людей советую в Android Studio перелезть!Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Вам это может показаться удивительным,но перед тем, как отобразить разметку, система android парсит (точнее инфлейтит) ее и преобразует в java-классы. В ваших классах нет траблов, а в классах, полученных в результате инфлейта вашей разметки - есть. В чем эти траблы и написано в стектрейсе.